# Alternative of Join in below SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In below query we are adding number of days on "move_out_date" depending on the "property_id".

We have written below query and It works fine.

But the problem is if there are n number of properties we need to use join for n times(in below case only 2 properties).

Is there any better and optimized way to get it done?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    leases l
    JOIN lease_processes lp ON ( lp.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lp.lease_id = l.id AND lp.customer_id IS NULL )
    JOIN lease_customers lc ON ( lc.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lc.lease_id = l.id AND lc.customer_id = l.primary_customer_id )
WHERE
    l.management_company_id = 2636
    AND lp.fmo_processed_on IS NULL
    AND lc.lease_status_type_id = 6
    AND ( lp.move_out_date + INTERVAL '5 day'  <= date(NOW()) AND l.property_id = 28949 )

UNION

SELECT
    *
FROM
    leases l
    JOIN lease_processes lp ON ( lp.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lp.lease_id = l.id AND lp.customer_id IS NULL )
    JOIN lease_customers lc ON ( lc.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lc.lease_id = l.id AND lc.customer_id = l.primary_customer_id )
WHERE
    l.management_company_id = 2636
    AND lp.fmo_processed_on IS NULL
    AND lc.lease_status_type_id = 6
    AND ( lp.move_out_date + INTERVAL '1 day'  <= date(NOW()) AND l.property_id = 28098 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    leases l
    JOIN lease_processes lp ON ( lp.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lp.lease_id = l.id AND lp.customer_id IS NULL )
    JOIN lease_customers lc ON ( lc.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lc.lease_id = l.id AND lc.customer_id = l.primary_customer_id )
WHERE
    l.management_company_id = 2636
    AND lp.fmo_processed_on IS NULL
    AND lc.lease_status_type_id = 6
    AND ( ( lp.move_out_date + INTERVAL '5 day'  <= date(NOW())) OR ( lp.move_out_date + INTERVAL '1 day'  <= date(NOW())))
    AND l.property_id = 28949
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider editing your tags so we can actually tell what your environment is.

Unless I've missed something you're not touching the join conditions just changing the where clause. That being the case you could use an appropriate conditional like CASE  or more appropriately you could save your literal interval values ('1 day', etc.) into an attribute of the leases table record for the relevant property and then filter on a single computed value.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    leases l
    JOIN lease_processes lp ON ( lp.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lp.lease_id = l.id AND lp.customer_id IS NULL )
    JOIN lease_customers lc ON ( lc.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND lc.lease_id = l.id AND lc.customer_id = l.primary_customer_id )
WHERE
    l.management_company_id = 2636
    AND lp.fmo_processed_on IS NULL
    AND lc.lease_status_type_id = 6
    AND ( lp.move_out_date + l.property_moveout_interval <= date(NOW()) 
AND l.property_id in var_some_aggregated_ID_list )
```

Comment: It is PostgreSQL. I guess above query will not work because property_moveout_interval is different for all properties.